# Search and edit value in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I've got a MongoDB collection that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Entry 1",
        "visible": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Entry 2",
        "visible": true
    }
]
```

I want to find the entry whose `title` matches my query (say, `array("title" => "Entry 1")`), and change its `visible` property.

This seems so incredibly simple, but I haven't found any way to do it. I see how to return the entry I want as an array. It seems to me I shouldn't have to fetch the entire object (which has many more properties than this example), change one small thing, then put the entire object again. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator)

```
db.pos.insert({arr: [{"title": "Entry 1", "visible": true},     
                     {"title": "Entry 2", "visible": true}]})

db.pos.update({'arr.title': 'Entry 1'}, 
              {$set: {'arr.$.visible': false}})

db.pos.find()
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4fdfb65e9c9cf2c23bbdd669"), "arr" : [     {   "title" : "Entry 1",    "visible" : false },    {   "title" : "Entry 2",    "visible" : true } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple!